# Incomplete req.body on Sails.js application

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I'm having a issue with a simple form submission on a `Sails.js` application. When in development, the req.body call works perfectly, but when I deploy the app on the `ubuntu 14.04` server it just sends a incomplete version of what I'd expect.

I'm not sure if this is important, but it's interesting that the two fields that aren't sending their information are `<select>` input fields.

I tried different versions of node and also reinstalled all dependencies.

Thank you for the help!